# Extract string between after second / and before -

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field that holds an account code. I've managed to extract the first 2 parts OK but I'm struggling with the last 2.

The field data is as follows:

```
812330/50110/0-0  
812330/50110/BDG001-0  
812330/50110/0-X001
```

I need to get the string between the second "/" and the "-" and after the "-" .Both fields have variable lengths, so I would be looking to output 0 and 0 on the first record, BDG001 and 0 on the second record and 0 and X001 on the third record.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the first half of the code fixed length? Up to the second slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CHARINDEX` and `LEFT/RIGHT`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO #tab VALUES ('812330/50110/0-0'),('812330/50110/BDG001-0'),
('812330/50110/0-X001');

WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    col,
    r = RIGHT(col, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(col))-1)
  FROM #tab
)
SELECT col, 
        r,
        sub1 = LEFT(r, CHARINDEX('-', r)-1),
        sub2 = RIGHT(r, LEN(r) - CHARINDEX('-', r))
FROM cte;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386861)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

or even simpler:

```
SELECT 
  col
  ,sub1 = SUBSTRING(col,
              LEN(col) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(col)) + 2,
               CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(col)) -CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(col))-1)
  ,sub2 = RIGHT(col, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(col))-1)
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386881)**</kbd>

**EDIT 2:**

Using `PARSENAME` **SQL SERVER 2012+** (if your data does not contain `.`):

```
SELECT 
  col,
  sub1 = PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '/', '.'), '-', '.'), 2),
  sub2 = PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '/', '.'), '-', '.'), 1)
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386884)**</kbd>

Comment: Don't you need to reverse a second time?

Comment: @shawnt00 The reverse is used only to get second `/` char.

Comment: My bad. I guess my excuse is the small screen on this phone :)

Answer (score 1):

...Or you can do this, so you only go from left side to right, so you don't need to count from the end in case you have more '/' or '-' signs:

```
SELECT 

SUBSTRING(columnName, CHARINDEX('/' , columnName, CHARINDEX('/' , columnName) + 1) + 1,
CHARINDEX('-', columnName) - CHARINDEX('/' , columnName, CHARINDEX('/' , columnName) + 1) - 1) AS FirstPart,
SUBSTRING(columnName, CHARINDEX('-' , columnName) + 1, LEN(columnName)) AS LastPart

 FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

One method way is to download a `split()` function off the web and use it.  However, the values end up in separate rows, not separate columns.  An alternative is a series of nested subqueries, CTEs, or `outer applies`:

```
select t.*, p1.part1, p12.part2, p12.part3
from table t outer apply
     (select t.*,
             left(t.field, charindex('/', t.field)) as part1,
             substring(t.field, charindex('/', t.field) + 1) as rest1
     ) p1 outer apply
     (select left(p1.rest1, charindex('/', p1.rest1) as part2,
             substring(p1.rest1, charindex('/', p1.rest1) + 1, len(p1.rest1)) as part3
     ) p12
where t.field like '%/%/%';
```

The `where` clause guarantees that the field value is in the right format.  Otherwise, you need to start sprinkling the code with `case` statements to handle misformated data.